# create a portal with php and joomla

Tags: php, joomla

I am new in `php` and `joomla` and for now, studying book "`Sams Teach Yourself PHP in 24 hour`".

I want to create an portal with PHP (and `Joomla`) that certain people with definite level of access can input data or use data...

Please tell me how should I do this? I must start from what and where?

Is reading `PHP` and be familiar with `Joomla` is enough?

Thanks in Advance...

Comment: What kind of portal, you could build a portal with Joomla alone without any php coding but the basic access levels in Joomla is limited, basically you can only have public or restricted.

Comment: you should really accept previous answers, 25% will make people not want to answer because they won't get credit for those answers

Comment: This question is extremely broad, can you be more specific?

Comment: ACL in Joomla is pretty limited. Why don't you try Drupal instead?

Answer (score 0):

Knowing PHP should be enough, and i don't know Joomla in detail, but i think only Joomla also might do the trick alone, and if so this might be way less work to do, depending on how exactly you want your portal to be.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think You need to study php. You better learn more about Joomla. There are many options to set priviledges and stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Joomla allows different access levels, but you must decide whether they fit your users' needs yourself. I would advise checking this out prior to starting the project: http://help.joomla.org/content/view/228/153/1/1/

Answer (score 0):

You can run and extend a Joomla site with no knowledge of PHP at all. Since your question isn't specific it is hard to give an exact answer, but I can point you in the right direction. Since you need access control levels, you definitely want to use Joomla 1.6. It has very good ACL that you can use to control every part of the site.

As for as a "portal" that really depends on your needs. Joomla has built in user registration as well as user submitted content, but it is rather limited in scope. If you are looking for a full blown community portal then you should take a look at JomSocial (will be 1.6 ready soon). More details on what your portal needs would be helpful though.